# TSQL Insert syntax vs. MySql

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have used this syntax in Mysql :

```
insert into mytable set firstname='Jo' , set lastname='mvc' ;
```

Is that also valid in TSQL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For SQL Server you want this syntax for updates:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET firstname='Jo', lastname='mvc' 
WHERE someCondition;
```

(assuming you don't want to update every row, you also need a WHERE clause)

and this for INSERTS:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (firstname, lastname) 
VALUES ('Jo', 'mvc');
```

Comment: that is true ... I forgot about the 'where' condition.

Answer (score 3):

No. Insert statement should look like this

```
insert into mytable (firstname, lastname)
values ('Jo', 'mvc');
```

If you meant update it would look like this:

```
update mytable set
  firstname='Jo',
  lastname='mvc'
```

With a where clause after if you like.

Comment: you are talking about TSQL , are you ? I was trying to check if my mysql statements can be ported to tsql with little efforts.

Comment: @user - Yes, this how you need to do it in TSQL.